# Can't get mysql_insert_id() method to grab value I need

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to grab SID from the insert into the first table (stories) so I can insert that SID into the writing table in my second insert.

I think the way to do this is with `mysql_insert_id();` after the first query, but the primary key that auto-increments is called SID. If `mysql_insert_id()` could grab that value I'd be all set.

What I am finding from a var_dump is that the   `$SID = mysql_insert_id();` is just returning the `value "0"` and I'm not sure why.

There is a column called ID in stores, but if it was grabbing that, the value would be `"1"`. Either way, I wish this method could be written as `mysql_insert_SID();`

Any idea what I am doing wrong or how I can fix this? And yes, I know this is a deprecated approach, but first I want to figure out how before I worry about converting to PDO.

```
// Get values from form 
$category = $_POST['category'];
$genre = $_POST['genre'];
$story_name = $_POST['story_name'];
$text = $_POST['text'];


$query = "INSERT INTO stories (ID, category, genre, story_name, active)  VALUES
('$user_ID', '$category', '$genre','$story_name', '1')";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$SID = mysql_insert_id();     
$SID2 = "select stories.SID from stories where stories.SID=$SID";

$query2 = "INSERT INTO writing (ID, SID, text, position, approved) 
VALUES('$user_ID',  '$SID2', '$text', '1','N')";


$result = mysql_query($query2);
```

Comment: where did u executed your query :D

Comment: I've used the above successfully. Can you run a `show create table stories` for us to confirm that your SID field is autoincrement? Because `mysql_insert_id()` will return 0 if there is no autoincrement field.

Comment: You're not executing ANY queries.

Comment: Sorry...I am executing the queries...I just left off that part which I have now added to the post. Also, the SID is definitely auto-increment and primary key for stories table

Comment: Add this line `echo mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error();` before you call `mysql_insert_id()` to make sure there's no error on inserting.

Comment: Or modify your call toward database like this `if(mysql_query($query)){ $sid = mysql_insert_id(); }else{ echo "Beep!"; }` and you'll show if you really inserted a record.

Comment: Thanks. I am inserting the SID record into stories and it is being returned and stored into the SID variable. I just can't get the second query to insert that SID. It still just shows 0 in writing table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've forgotten to execute the query most probably?
Try

```
$SID = mysql_insert_id();
```

after executing the query

```
$query = "INSERT INTO stories (ID, category, genre, story_name, active)  VALUES
('$user_ID', '$category', '$genre','$story_name', '1')";

$result = mysql_query($query); // executing

$SID = mysql_insert_id(); // order of queries is important
```

Comment: Sorry...I am executing the queries...I just left off that part which I have now added to the post. Also, the SID is definitely auto-increment and primary key for stories

Comment: You are executing the query `$result = mysql_query($query);` after executing  `$SID = mysql_insert_id();` Check the updated answer out

Comment: I just implemented your update. So close...my var_dump() is now showing that $SID now is getting the right SID number. But in the writing table the SID is still 0 after the second insert.

Comment: Well, i solved the rest. The problem was is $SID2 = "select stories.SID from stories where stories.SID=$SID";  All it was returning was "select stories.SID from stories where stories.SID=$SID". So I just set it to $SID2 = $SID; and it works. Any idea why the variable was returning the query string and not the query result? I tried putting in backets too...

Comment: You need to execute that query too and then fetch the result as an array and assign $SID2 to that resultant array. Check mysql_fetch_assoc() method and try `$query3 = "select stories.SID from stories where stories.SID=$SID";
$result3 = mysql_query($query3);
$row     = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3);
$SID2    = $row['SID'];`

Answer (score 3):

> Retrieves the ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query (usually INSERT).

(http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

But you aren't executing any query (via `mysql_query()`). You're just assigning your query to a variable. Try following:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO stories (ID, category, genre, story_name, active)  VALUES
('$user_ID', '$category', '$genre','$story_name', '1')";
mysql_query($query);
$SID = mysql_insert_id();
```

Comment: Sorry...I am executing the queries...I just left off that part which I have now added to the post. Also, the SID is definitely auto-increment and primary key for stories. What you wrote about the definition of mysql_insert_id() is exactly what I need to do, so I am on the right track I believe with this approach. But it still same result of 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot get the value through mysql_insert_id() then try `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`. Of course there will be a value if you have executed an insert query with AUTOINCREMENT (which you haven't done yet)

Comment: I guess this is my backup plan I will try next. I'm so close on the other method though.